# stop scroll event when another event is fired

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

I'm trying to stop scrollTo event when wheel , keyup, down or swipe is fired but i cannot find a way in angular using typescript

```
scrollTop() {
(function smoothscroll() {
  const currentScroll =
    document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (currentScroll > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(smoothscroll);
    window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll - currentScroll / 8);
  }
})();
```

}

than in html:

```
<button (click)="scrollTop()" #scrollToTop class="back-to-top">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'arrow-up']"></fa-icon>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in your current component / service to track if you want to keep scrolling:

```
type ScrollState = 'scrolling-up' | 'stopped'

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComponent {
  scrolling: ScrollState = 'stopped';
  
  @ViewChild('scrollToTop')
  scrollTopButton: ElementRef<HTMLButton>;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('document:touchstart', ['$event'])
  documentClick(event: any): void {
    if (!this.scrollToTop.nativeElement.contains(ev.target)) {
      this.scrolling = 'stopped';
    }
  }

  scrollTop() {
    this.scrolling = 'scrolling-up';
    this.nextScrollTick();
  }

  nextScrollTick() {
    const currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (this.scrolling === 'stopped' || currentScroll < 0) {
      return;
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, currentScroll - currentScroll / 8);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.nextScrollTick());
  }
}
```

Sidenote: too many `HostListener`s can become quite costly and should be centralized (in a service)

Comment: thank you so much, this solution is exaclty what i was looking for, working fine.